# iOS simulator freezes (hangs) when running detox tests

Tags: ios, integration-testing, simulator, detox

We're having an issue when running our e2e test suite, particularly when running on CI (Bitrise).

During the test suite, a few tests (different on each run) will error out with:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 120000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 120000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

      at mapper (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:25:45)
```

What actually happens is the simulator freezes and becomes unresponsive (it's impossible to click on anything, use the keyboard, turn it off using the rendered power button; you need to kill it using Cmd+W, or restart using Hardware menu). When it happens, all following tests in the given file fail with a Timeout error.

Then, when we're starting a new test suite (new spec file), a new simulator is opened by Detox and the tests carry on... until this happens again.
I've seen it happens 2 times in the test suite, resulting in 3 simulators being open (2 of them frozen).

*Logs*

```
detox[37080] TRACE: [ArtifactsManager.js/LIFECYCLE] artifactsManager.onBeforeEach({ title: 'should go to OOO page',
  fullName: 'Backup Plan Preferences should go to OOO page',
  status: 'running' })
detox[37080] TRACE: [Artifact.js/START] starting SimulatorLogRecording
detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #36] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl get_app_container 2CF919FD-473E-4386-9EE0-57A0DD2009E1 com.myeatclub.EAT-Club
detox[37080] TRACE: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #36] /Users/magdalenastrzoda/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2CF919FD-473E-4386-9EE0-57A0DD2009E1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F833DF08-D432-4AFE-AD50-E5311F77F0B8/EatClubMobileApp.app
detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/SPAWN_CMD, #37] [pid=47331] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl spawn 2CF919FD-473E-4386-9EE0-57A0DD2009E1 log stream --level debug --style compact --predicate "processImagePath beginsWith \"/Users/magdalenastrzoda/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2CF919FD-473E-4386-9EE0-57A0DD2009E1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F833DF08-D432-4AFE-AD50-E5311F77F0B8/EatClubMobileApp.app\""
detox[37080] TRACE: [Artifact.js/START] starting SimulatorVideoRecording
detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/SPAWN_CMD, #38] [pid=47333] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl io 2CF919FD-473E-4386-9EE0-57A0DD2009E1 recordVideo /private/var/folders/qk/07x9s51136jdkzv7t2_q2n5h0000gp/T/3023bd5e-9332-42d0-bbc2-011dd505fea0.mp4
detox[37080] TRACE: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_SEND] {"type":"reactNativeReload","params":{},"messageId":-1000}
detox[37080] TRACE: [DetoxServer.js/MESSAGE] role=tester action=reactNativeReload (sessionId=5044f1e4-f0af-d762-ef72-799282ef295b)
detox[37080] TRACE: [DetoxServer.js/MESSAGE] role=testee action=ready (sessionId=5044f1e4-f0af-d762-ef72-799282ef295b)
detox[37080] TRACE: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_MESSAGE] {"type":"ready","messageId":-1000,"params":{}}

detox[37080] TRACE: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_SEND] {"type":"invoke","params":{"target":{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"EarlGrey","value":"instance"},"method":"detox_selectElementWithMatcher:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"detoxMatcherForBoth:and:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"matcherForAccessibilityID:","args":[{"type":"NSString","value":"account"}]}},{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"matcherForSufficientlyVisible","args":[]}}]}}]}},"method":"performAction:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYActions"},"method":"actionForTap","args":[]}}]},"messageId":312}
detox[37080] TRACE: [DetoxServer.js/MESSAGE] role=tester action=invoke (sessionId=5044f1e4-f0af-d762-ef72-799282ef295b)
detox[37080] TRACE: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_SEND] {"type":"invoke","params":{"target":{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYCondition"},"method":"detoxConditionForElementMatched:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"EarlGrey","value":"instance"},"method":"detox_selectElementWithMatcher:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"detoxMatcherForBoth:and:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"detoxMatcherForText:","args":[{"type":"NSString","value":"Out of Office"}]}},{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"matcherForNotNil","args":[]}}]}}]}}]}},"method":"waitWithTimeout:","args":[{"type":"CGFloat","value":4}]},"messageId":313}
detox[37080] TRACE: [DetoxServer.js/MESSAGE] role=tester action=invoke (sessionId=5044f1e4-f0af-d762-ef72-799282ef295b)
Backup Plan Preferences: should go to OOO page [FAIL]

detox[37080] TRACE: [Detox.js/DETOX_AFTER_EACH] failed test: "Backup Plan Preferences should go to OOO page"
detox[37080] TRACE: [ArtifactsManager.js/LIFECYCLE] artifactsManager.onAfterEach({ title: 'should go to OOO page',
  fullName: 'Backup Plan Preferences should go to OOO page',
  status: 'failed',
  timedOut: true })
detox[37080] TRACE: [Artifact.js/STOP] stopping SimulatorVideoRecording
detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/KILL] sending SIGINT to [pid = 47333]: /usr/bin/xcrun simctl io 2CF919FD-473E-4386-9EE0-57A0DD2009E1 recordVideo /private/var/folders/qk/07x9s51136jdkzv7t2_q2n5h0000gp/T/3023bd5e-9332-42d0-bbc2-011dd505fea0.mp4
FAIL e2e/backupPlan.spec.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 120000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 120000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

      at mapper (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:25:45)

detox[37080] INFO:  [DetoxServer.js] [32mserver listening on localhost:50310...
detox[37080] DEBUG: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_OPEN] opened web socket to: ws://localhost:50310
detox[37080] TRACE: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_SEND] {"type":"login","params":{"sessionId":"55fb73cb-c9d8-52cf-d2de-7411c43904da","role":"tester"},"messageId":0}
detox[37080] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN] role=tester, sessionId=55fb73cb-c9d8-52cf-d2de-7411c43904da
detox[37080] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN_SUCCESS] role=tester, sessionId=55fb73cb-c9d8-52cf-d2de-7411c43904da
detox[37080] TRACE: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_MESSAGE] {"type":"loginSuccess","params":{"sessionId":"55fb73cb-c9d8-52cf-d2de-7411c43904da","role":"tester"},"messageId":0}
detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #0] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl list -j
```

Log from a different test

```
Log In Screen: should error out after pressing log in button, use login button [OK]
Log In Screen: pressing enter should move user to next field or submit form
detox[37080] TRACE: [Detox.js/DETOX_AFTER_EACH] passed test: "Log In Screen should error out after pressing log in button, use login button"
detox[37080] TRACE: [ArtifactsManager.js/LIFECYCLE] artifactsManager.onAfterEach({ title:
   'should error out after pressing log in button, use login button',
  fullName:
   'Log In Screen should error out after pressing log in button, use login button',
  status: 'passed',
  timedOut: false })
detox[37080] TRACE: [Artifact.js/STOP] stopping SimulatorVideoRecording
detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/KILL] sending SIGINT to [pid = 78758]: /usr/bin/xcrun simctl io 0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE recordVideo /private/var/folders/qk/07x9s51136jdkzv7t2_q2n5h0000gp/T/29530a7b-b165-47e4-b04a-2ba64757c108.mp4
detox[37080] TRACE: [exec.js/SPAWN_END, #7] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl io 0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE recordVideo /private/var/folders/qk/07x9s51136jdkzv7t2_q2n5h0000gp/T/29530a7b-b165-47e4-b04a-2ba64757c108.mp4 finished with code = 0
detox[37080] TRACE: [Artifact.js/DISCARD] discarding SimulatorVideoRecording
detox[37080] TRACE: [Artifact.js/STOP] stopping SimulatorLogRecording
detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/KILL] sending SIGINT to [pid = 79304]: /usr/bin/xcrun simctl spawn 0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE log stream --level debug --style compact --predicate processImagePath beginsWith "/Users/llostris/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2AAE2241-ADF4-4684-8534-C2EDC66C62E7/MyMobileApp.app"
detox[37080] TRACE: [exec.js/SPAWN_END, #13] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl spawn 0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE log stream --level debug --style compact --predicate "processImagePath beginsWith \"/Users/llostris/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2AAE2241-ADF4-4684-8534-C2EDC66C62E7/MyMobileApp.app\"" finished with code = 130
detox[37080] TRACE: [Artifact.js/DISCARD] discarding SimulatorLogRecording
detox[37080] TRACE: [Detox.js/DETOX_BEFORE_EACH] running test: "Log In Screen pressing enter should move user to next field or submit form"
detox[37080] TRACE: [ArtifactsManager.js/LIFECYCLE] artifactsManager.onBeforeEach({ title:
   'pressing enter should move user to next field or submit form',
  fullName:
   'Log In Screen pressing enter should move user to next field or submit form',
  status: 'running' })
detox[37080] TRACE: [Artifact.js/START] starting SimulatorLogRecording
detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #16] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl get_app_container 0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE com.myapp.MyApp
detox[37080] TRACE: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #16] /Users/llostris/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2AAE2241-ADF4-4684-8534-C2EDC66C62E7/MyMobileApp.app

detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/SPAWN_CMD, #17] [pid=81318] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl spawn 0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE log stream --level debug --style compact --predicate "processImagePath beginsWith \"/Users/llostris/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2AAE2241-ADF4-4684-8534-C2EDC66C62E7/MyMobileApp.app\""
detox[37080] TRACE: [Artifact.js/START] starting SimulatorVideoRecording
detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/SPAWN_CMD, #18] [pid=81320] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl io 0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE recordVideo /private/var/folders/qk/07x9s51136jdkzv7t2_q2n5h0000gp/T/b4900464-683e-462d-a512-742295847245.mp4
  console.log e2e/starterKit.js:359
    Applying kits...

  console.log e2e/starterKit.js:360
    []

detox[37080] TRACE: [ArtifactsManager.js/LIFECYCLE] artifactsManager.onBeforeTerminateApp({ deviceId: '0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE',
  bundleId: 'com.myapp.MyApp' })
detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #19] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl terminate 0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE com.myapp.MyApp
detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #19] Terminating com.myapp.MyApp...
detox[37080] TRACE: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #19] 
detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #19] com.myapp.MyApp terminated
detox[37080] TRACE: [ArtifactsManager.js/LIFECYCLE] artifactsManager.onBeforeUninstallApp({ deviceId: '0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE',
  bundleId: 'com.myapp.MyApp' })
detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #20] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl uninstall 0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE com.myapp.MyApp
detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #20] Uninstalling com.myapp.MyApp...
detox[37080] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/DISCONNECT] role=testee, sessionId=1e596070-18a4-4199-2f91-9334c11f7b3c
detox[37080] TRACE: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_MESSAGE] {"type":"testeeDisconnected","messageId":-49642}

detox[37080] TRACE: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #20] 
detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #20] com.myapp.MyApp uninstalled
detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #21] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl install 0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE "/Users/llostris/Code/iris/ios/build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/MyMobileApp.app"
detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #21] Installing /Users/llostris/Code/iris/ios/build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/MyMobileApp.app...
detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #21] Installing /Users/llostris/Code/iris/ios/build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/MyMobileApp.app...
detox[37080] TRACE: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #21] 
detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #21] /Users/llostris/Code/iris/ios/build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/MyMobileApp.app installed
detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #22] applesimutils --byId 0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE --bundle com.myapp.MyApp --restartSB --setPermissions calendar=YES,notifications=YES
detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #22] Trying to set permissions...
detox[37080] TRACE: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #22] 
detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #22] Permissions are set
detox[37080] TRACE: [ArtifactsManager.js/LIFECYCLE] artifactsManager.onBeforeLaunchApp({ bundleId: 'com.myapp.MyApp',
  deviceId: '0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE',
  launchArgs:
   { detoxServer: 'ws://localhost:51686',
     detoxSessionId: '1e596070-18a4-4199-2f91-9334c11f7b3c' } })
detox[37080] TRACE: [Artifact.js/START] starting SimulatorLogRecording { udid: '0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE',
  bundleId: 'com.myapp.MyApp' }
detox[37080] TRACE: [Artifact.js/STOP] stopping SimulatorLogRecording
detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/KILL] sending SIGINT to [pid = 81318]: /usr/bin/xcrun simctl spawn 0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE log stream --level debug --style compact --predicate processImagePath beginsWith "/Users/llostris/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2AAE2241-ADF4-4684-8534-C2EDC66C62E7/MyMobileApp.app"
detox[37080] TRACE: [exec.js/SPAWN_END, #17] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl spawn 0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE log stream --level debug --style compact --predicate "processImagePath beginsWith \"/Users/llostris/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2AAE2241-ADF4-4684-8534-C2EDC66C62E7/MyMobileApp.app\"" finished with code = 130
detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #23] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl get_app_container 0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE com.myapp.MyApp
detox[37080] TRACE: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #23] /Users/llostris/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7AC323BB-906A-4E1C-BB2C-FC71F07430AB/MyMobileApp.app

detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/SPAWN_CMD, #24] [pid=82101] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl spawn 0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE log stream --level debug --style compact --predicate "processImagePath beginsWith \"/Users/llostris/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7AC323BB-906A-4E1C-BB2C-FC71F07430AB/MyMobileApp.app\""
detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #25] SIMCTL_CHILD_DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES="/Users/llostris/Library/Detox/ios/6388df0390fc38dbea2fc3622b24074567ce5280/Detox.framework/Detox" /usr/bin/xcrun simctl launch 0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE com.myapp.MyApp --args -detoxServer "ws://localhost:51686" -detoxSessionId "1e596070-18a4-4199-2f91-9334c11f7b3c"
detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #25] Launching com.myapp.MyApp...
detox[37080] TRACE: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_SEND] {"type":"invoke","params":{"target":{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"EarlGrey","value":"instance"},"method":"detox_selectElementWithMatcher:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"detoxMatcherForText:","args":[{"type":"NSString","value":"Welcome back"}]}}]}},"method":"assertWithMatcher:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"matcherForSufficientlyVisible","args":[]}}]},"messageId":15}
detox[37080] TRACE: [DetoxServer.js/MESSAGE] role=tester action=invoke (sessionId=1e596070-18a4-4199-2f91-9334c11f7b3c)
detox[37080] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/CANNOT_FORWARD] role=testee not connected, cannot fw action (sessionId=1e596070-18a4-4199-2f91-9334c11f7b3c)
Log In Screen: pressing enter should move user to next field or submit form [FAIL]
Log In Screen: user should be able to log in to the app
detox[37080] TRACE: [Detox.js/DETOX_AFTER_EACH] failed test: "Log In Screen pressing enter should move user to next field or submit form"
detox[37080] TRACE: [ArtifactsManager.js/LIFECYCLE] artifactsManager.onAfterEach({ title:
   'pressing enter should move user to next field or submit form',
  fullName:
   'Log In Screen pressing enter should move user to next field or submit form',
  status: 'failed',
  timedOut: true })
detox[37080] TRACE: [Artifact.js/STOP] stopping SimulatorVideoRecording
detox[37080] DEBUG: [exec.js/KILL] sending SIGINT to [pid = 81320]: /usr/bin/xcrun simctl io 0581BF22-BCAF-41EF-8BC3-41B54CA845AE recordVideo /private/var/folders/qk/07x9s51136jdkzv7t2_q2n5h0000gp/T/b4900464-683e-462d-a512-742295847245.mp4
```

Any hints on how to resolve this?

It makes it impossible for us to run our tests on CI, as this happens at least 50% of the time.

*Environment*

- Detox: 12.11.3, also tested with 13.0.3 - same thing
- React Native: 0.59.9
- Node: 10.14.2
- Device: iPhone 6
- Xcode: 10.1
- iOS: 12.1
- macOS: 10.14.5
- applesimutils: 0.7, tested also with 0.6.7, 0.6.6 - same thing happens
- Simulator app version: 10.1 (SimulatorApp-877 CoreSimulator-587.35)

Comment: Can you reproduce this locally? When you do, once the simulator hangs, open Activity Monitor and see what process is consuming a lot of CPU. Let's make sure it's the simulator itself. Once you find that process, sample the process and update your question with the sample stack.

Comment: If it's the simulator runtime itself that is stuck, it's an Apple bug. Seeing as you are on an old version of Xcode, I'd recommend upgrading Xcode.

Comment: Okay, we'll try upgrading to Xcode 10.2.

We've managed to reproduce it locally, first using bitrise-cli, and then running the tests in a clean repo. There is no process that is consuming a lot of CPU actually, the CPU usage is low except for entirely unrealted tasks i.e. my browser etc. 

Here's the sample of the actual Simulator app when it hangs: https://gist.github.com/llostris/59d68b94a138a3508206d9b62e815a6d

Comment: Sadly, exactly the same thing happens after upgrading to Xcode 10.2.

Comment: From the sample you provided, it seems like a deadlock between two threads. I suggest opening a bug report with Apple: https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/

Comment: I've been running into this as well very recently. A few things I noticed, if VPN is running on my MAC at the time of the tests run, they will definitely hang. There is no specific point at which the Simulator would hang (it is completely random). There is no specific simulator config that is guaranteed to hang (that is also completely random). I have written a script to run my Detox tests on several iOS sim configs one after the other. At the end, I just stopped opening the Simulator app. Basically, I'm running all tests perfectly fine in 'headless' mode.

Comment: @JanithaR How do you run the detox tests on iOS in headless mode? When running on Bitrise, the test runner automatically starts the simulator app for us, and according to the docs --headless works only on Android?

Comment: Also as per Leo's request I have submitted a report in Feedback Assistant, but this hasn't been resolved yet. In the mean time we went back to using iPhone X on Xcode 10.2, as it seems to be the most stable simulator of the ones we tested. It still hangs sometimes though.

Comment: I only test on my Mac and starting tests do not start up the simulator app automatically. I spoke too soon though. Even without the simulator app running my tests timeout and started hanging. Very frustrating.